# setting android:background is messing up the text for my radiobutton

Tags: android

I built this for Android 2.2

Here is my code. The java is generated by eclipse. The xml I changed.

```
package foo.bar.radiobuttontest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import foo.bar.radiobuttontest.R;

public class rbt extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

here is my res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RadioGroup
      android:id="@+id/orientation"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="5px">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/horizontal"
            android:background="#aa0000"
            android:text="horizontal"
        />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/vertical"
            android:text="vertical"
        />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

While experimenting with radiobuttons I started making a very simple app. It looks like this:

* horizontal * vertical

For no good reason I thought I would change the background color. I started by changing the background of the RadioGroup element, everything worked just as expected. Then just for fun I though I would change the background of only one of the radio buttons in the group. This can be seen in main.xml above. After doing this I noticed the text of the radiobutton is now covered by the radiobutton, the page now looks something like:

*rizontal * vertical

Except you can still kind of see the 'ho' from horizontal they are just covered by the radiobutton

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I would...definitely not call that expected behavior. Trying it myself, the only thing I can think of is that they used an empty NinePatch with a limited content area...but that seems EXTREMELY unlikely.

Comment: Just discovered the same thing!  Sigh.  Did you find any other answers or work-arounds?

Comment: No. This was just a toy program I was playing. I will probably never revisit this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been searching a bit and I've found that what @kcoppock proposed was right. [Here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/values/styles.xml&q=public.xml&d=3&l=260) you find radio button style, and [this](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/btn_radio_label_background.9.png) is the referenced background image:

[image]

It's a nine-patch whose content area excludes the "radio" area. I guess one could start from this image to make a custom background.

Comment: This is definatly a weird approach IMHO. By setting the background to anything (color, @null, image, nine-patch) you can modify the content area for the text. Be aware that the android:button image is layered above the text for a RadioButton

Comment: My custom background image (a nine-patch) also does the same thing to the text and/or additional image (android:drawableRight, for example).  So this doesn't help--any other suggestions?